# Finding Eigenvalues of this matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the Eigenvalues of the following matrix.

[image]

$c_i$ are reals.

I tried to compute the characteristic polynomial, but it is quite tedious.

Comment: Self work? Background: where does this come from, what for...? What are $\;c_i\;$ ...?

Comment: This is a quote from the posting guidelines: "Including your work also shows to the community that you're not using this website as an answer machine -- as such, your question will be received more positively."

Anyway, just from glancing at this matrix, I see that it will have lots of eigenvectors of the form (1, 0, 0, ..., 0, -1, 0, ... , 0), as well as the eigenvector (c1, c2, ..., cn). This should get you started.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have added some details. I don't know how to add matrix in LaTeX.

Comment: This matrix is in a form where it's easy to see the eigenvectors, so it may be easier to get the eigenvalues directly using the eigenvectors. Also, note that the range of this matrix is only one dimensional, so by the rank nullity theorem, the nullspace is dimension $n-1$. So you should be able to get $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=c_1+\ldots+c_n$ then $\det(A-\lambda I)=
\begin{vmatrix}
c_1-\lambda& c_1&\ldots&c_1\\
c_2& c_2-\lambda& \ldots&c_2\\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots&\ldots\\
c_n& c_n& \ldots&c_n-\lambda\\ 
\end{vmatrix}=(S-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
1& 1&\ldots&1\\
c_2& c_2-\lambda& \ldots&c_2\\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots&\ldots\\
c_n& c_n& \ldots&c_n-\lambda\\
\end{vmatrix}=\ldots
$

Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you tell me when is the last determinant 0?

Comment: @Alex 2 subtract the first column from all the others